# Combine extract and tcolorbox

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, extract

I was formatting my class notes and used `\tcolorboxenvironment` from the `tcolorbox` package with `proof` from `amsmath` for a new formatting for my proofs. This is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, report]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{% 'proof' from 'amsthm'
    blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
    before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        $ $\newline
        This is a proof.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

And it compiled just as expected to build this

[image: MWE]

However, later on I used the `extract` package and although the code didn't present any warnings or errors, compiling just as great, the `tcolorbox` formatting disappeared from my original file, with proofs going back to the usual proof-style formatting from `amsmath`, but worked just fine in the new file `proofs` created by the `extract`package. So my original code stopped doing what it did, but the copy worked just great.

Why don't `extract` and `tcolorbox` work together in this case?

Here's the previous code with the addition of the `extract` package

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, report, oneside, reqno]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{% 'proof' from 'amsthm'
    blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
    before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
}

\usepackage[active, copydocumentclass=true, generate=proofs, extract-env={proof}]{extract} 

\begin{extract}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable}

    \tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{% 'proof' from 'amsthm'
        blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
        borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
    }   
\end{extract}


\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        $ $\newline
        This is a proof.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

And here's the print of this last build

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: Move the `tcolorbox` stuff after `extract`.

[image: proof]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, report, oneside, reqno]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[active, copydocumentclass=true, generate=proofs, extract-env={proof}]{extract} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{% 'proof' from 'amsthm'
    blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
    before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
}

\begin{extract}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable}

    \tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{% 'proof' from 'amsthm'
        blanker,breakable,left=5mm,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
        borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}
    }   
\end{extract}


\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        $ $\newline
        This is a proof.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't see it coming so simply, thank you. I'd like to understand why it worked though, should I update the question?

Comment: @user71487 I can only guess there, but probably, because `tcolorboxenvironment` somehow patches the environment and `extract` does too, so the order is important.